# Does dipping something metal in alcohol sterilize it?

Tags: infection, prevention, alcohol, metal

Since childhood, some people told me that wetting a metal utensil in alcohol could sterilize it. How true is this?

Comment: Isn't that the same reason alcohol used to be used for disinfecting wounds? Rubbing alcohol comes to mind.

Comment: @MasterYoda I'm interested to know if it kills the bacterium Clostridium tetani

Comment: I think the same discussion is going on here-http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=255406